# I'm not getting Preg_match_all

Tags: wordpress, image, preg-match-all

Im looking to find an image (by shortcode [image]...[/image] in my Wordpress posts to set as a featured image. As I'm using the code of the plugin Auto Save Remote Images, I thought this would work, but it doesn't.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

```
    if(preg_match_all('/.image./(.*?)/..image./', $post->post_content, $matches)){
    $first_image = $matches [1] [0];
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following (not knowing how your shortcode actually looks like)

```
if(preg_match_all('/\[image\](.*?)\[\/image\]/', $post->post_content, $matches)){
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However, my scheduled import of 500+ posts was timed-out when i tried to save the remote images also. Seemed like this wasn't the problem :).